# Find and convert all strings starts with http & https and convert into links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to find all strings starts with http & https in a paragraph and convert into links using jquery?

I got my twitt list in my website and all lines starts with http & https display as normal string [text]. I want to convert them into hyperlinks. Is this possible with javascript, jQuery.

Comment: Why the [tag:PHP] tag, if you want to do it in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is code to check URL's in string and convert it as link. This will detect links which are started with WWW also. Hope this will helps.

```
function Checkurl(text) {
        var url1 = /(^|&lt;|\s)(www\..+?\..+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g,
        url2 = /(^|&lt;|\s)(((https?|ftp):\/\/|mailto:).+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g;

        var html = $.trim(text);
        if (html) {
            html = html
                .replace(url1, '$1<a style="color:blue; text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank"  href="http://$2">$2</a>$3')
                .replace(url2, '$1<a style="color:blue; text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank"  href="$2">$2</a>$5');
        }
        return html;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var linkable_content = $('div#linkable').html().replace(/(https?:\/\/[^ ;|\\*'"!,()<>]+\/?)/g,'<a href="$1">$1</a>');
    $('div#linkable').html(linkable_content);
});
```

Source: http://tangible.ca/articles/44/snippet-jquery-linkifier

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I'll change my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The following utility function from the [jQuery WikiText Plugin](http://www.kajabity.com/jquery-wikitext/usage.html) will work:

```
function findUrls( text )
{
    var source = (text || '').toString();
    var urlArray = [];
    var url;
    var matchArray;

    // Regular expression to find FTP, HTTP(S) and email URLs.
    var regexToken = /(((ftp|https?):\/\/)[\-\w@:%_\+.~#?,&\/\/=]+)|((mailto:)?[_.\w-]+@([\w][\w\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,3})/g;

    // Iterate through any URLs in the text.
    while( (matchArray = regexToken.exec( source )) !== null )
    {
        var token = matchArray[0];
        urlArray.push( token );
    }

    return urlArray;
}
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zyXky/).

I hope this helps!