# Regex for url validation works in a tester but not in javascript function

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a URL validation that I am doing that is very relaxed and more or less just guiding the user to make sure they enter close to a URL.

So I have got a regex that is doing what I want in a tester. (Only Multiline Selected)
ex: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

However, when I call it in my code, it gives different results.

```
isURLValid: function (value) {
    var urlRegex = new RegExp("^((http|https|ftp)\://)*([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$");
    return urlRegex.test(value);
}
```

Requirements:
Must support http, https, non http, non https, www, and non-www URL schemes

Valid

```
http://www.adamthings.com
https://www.adamthings.com
www.adamthings.com
adamthings.com
```

Invalid

```
http://www.adamthings 
https://www.adamthings
www.adamthings
adamthings
```

Results work in the tester, in code I get all of the above are valid.  Why does the regex react differently?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318023/find-and-convert-all-strings-starts-with-http-https-and-convert-into-links)

Comment: You need to double-escape your caret:
Otherwise javascript doesn't interpret the backslash as a backslash, and therefore never escapes the caret for the regex

Comment: FWIW I always use regex planet..

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript: `"\.com" === ".com"` (I think it's not you want.)
Try `/regex/` instead of `new RegExp("regex")` to create a regex.

Comment: Doing /regex/ gives a bunch of syntax errors. I am not sure what would need escaped doing it this way, I am still getting my head fully around Regex.

Comment: @Adam - that's because you have to escape the `/` char in the regex when using the `/regex/` syntax.

Comment: Using /regex/ and then escaping the / char did what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow something like

```
adamthings.com
```

which has no leading `http://`, `https://`, `ftp://` or `www.` part, then you would need to list all allowed TLDs, such as `com`, `net`, etc., to prevent input such as

```
john.doe
```

to be valid as well.

Then your regex pattern should look like

```
^(?:https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?!www\.)(?:(?!-)[a-z\d-]*[a-z\d]\.)+(?:com|net)
```

which checks just domain part of the link.

If you want to go further and check trailing part or link, then you need to add

```
(?:\/[^\/\s]*)*$
```

to the first part of pattern, however this (part of regex pattern) does not validate the url.

» [Test link](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gim&regex=%5E%28%3F%3Ahttps%3F%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%7Cftp%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%29%3F%28%3F%3Awww%5C.%29%3F%28%3F!www%5C.%29%28%3F%3A%28%3F!-%29%5Ba-z%5Cd-%5D%2a%5Ba-z%5Cd%5D%5C.%29%2B%28%3F%3Acom%7Cnet%7Corg%29&input=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.adamthings.com%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.adamthings.com%0Awww.adamthings.com%0Aadamthings.com%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.adamthings%20%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.adamthings%0Awww.adamthings%0Aadamthings) «